# CodeIgniter Pagination Links removed after like query executes

Tags: codeigniter, pagination

`
**Controller :**

```
            $page = ($this->uri->segment(3)) ? $this->uri->segment(3) : 0;
            $config = array();
            $config['base_url'] = base_url().'tr_admin/billmanagement/'; 
            $config['total_rows'] = $this->bill_model->count_all_bill($this->session->userdata('searchBillRec'));
            $config['per_page'] = 100;  
            $config['use_page_numbers'] = TRUE;
            $config["uri_segment"] = 3; 
            $config['full_tag_open'] = '<ul class="pagination">';
            $config['full_tag_close'] = '</ul>';
            $config['use_page_numbers'] = FALSE;
            $config['next_link'] = 'Next';
            $config['next_tag_open'] = '<li class="next page">';
            $config['next_tag_close'] = '</li>';
            $config['prev_link'] = ' Previous';
            $config['prev_tag_open'] = '<li class="prev page">';
            $config['prev_tag_close'] = '</li>';
            $config['cur_tag_open'] = '<li class="active"><a href="">';
            $config['cur_tag_close'] = '</a></li>';
            $config['num_tag_open'] = '<li class="page">';
            $config['num_tag_close'] = '</li>';
            $data['recList'] = $this->bill_model->get_bill($config["per_page"],$page,$this->session->userdata('searchBillRec'));

            $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        
            $data['main_content'] = 'tr_admin/billmanagement';
            $this->load->view('tr_admin/includes/template', $data);
```

**Model:**

```
         if($filterData['bill_to']!=''){
                 $this->db->like('bill_to', $filterData['bill_to'],'both');
            }
        $this->db->order_by("bill_id","DESC");
            $this->db->limit($per_page,$page);
            return $this->db->get()->result_array();
        
 `
```

Comment: for WHERE clause it runs perfect

Comment: Could you please add a question in your post? Check ["How do I ask a good question"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

Pagination links only show when there's more results than the current offset you set. So if there's only 5 records and your offset is 10 then there's no pagination to do.